# Twilio not working with curl php

Tags: php, json, curl, twilio

im working on [TWILIO SMS](https://www.twilio.com/), I'm using trial account everything is working with pure php library, but i had a problem when using CURL & PHP

```
require "Services/Twilio.php";
$AccountSid = "SANDBOX_ACC_ID"; 
$AuthToken = "SANDBOX_TOKEN";
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
"From" => "+MAGICNUMBER",
"To" => "+XXXXXXXXXX",// twilio trial verified number
"Body" => "Test message 2 from Fedrick!",
));
// Display a confirmation message on the screen
echo "testing with php message {$message->sid}";
```

pure php output:

```
testing with php message SMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Code i have tried using CURL & PHP (which is not working)

```
$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/SANDBOX_ACC_ID/SMS/Messages.json";
$from = "+MAGICNUMBER";
$to = "+XXXXXXXXXX"; // twilio trial verified number
$body = "using twilio rest api from Fedrick";
$id = "SANDBOX_ACC_ID";
$token = "SANDBOX_TOKEN";
$data = array (
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Body' => $body,

    );
$post = http_build_query($data);
$x = curl_init($url );
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
var_dump($post);
$y = curl_exec($x);
var_dump($y);
curl_close($x);
```

OUTPUT using Curl php :

```
bool(false)
```

what wrong i have done in curl code... is there any solution without using pure php library, i want to use short and simple code just like above CURL code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, since API's URL is secured, you have to disable SSL peer verification by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to `false`.

Furthermore, according to [API docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), URL of request is account-dependent, i.e. it should be built based on your account sandbox ID:

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages
```

So the code should look like this:

```
$id = "SANDBOX_ACC_ID";
$token = "SANDBOX_TOKEN";
$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$id/SMS/Messages";
$from = "+MAGICNUMBER";
$to = "+XXXXXXXXXX"; // twilio trial verified number
$body = "using twilio rest api from Fedrick";
$data = array (
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Body' => $body,
);
$post = http_build_query($data);
$x = curl_init($url );
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$id:$token");
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$y = curl_exec($x);
curl_close($x);
var_dump($post);
var_dump($y);
```

Comment: +1 works great... how to format the var_dump($y), here the output is displaying without any format

Comment: @fedrick Since the response is JSON, you have to use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) before output

Comment: json_decode($x) before curl_close($y).. is it correct?

Comment: i think it is not returning json response... it is just displaying somedata on the screen

Comment: i have tried var_dump(json_decode($y)); it displays NULL

Comment: @fedrick So the response is most-likely HTML. Just `echo` it: `echo $y;`

Comment: yep it is html.. displaying same out put when i use echo $y and print_r($y)... have you used twilio api any time

Comment: @fedrick You could choose this answer as "accepted" as well if it solve your problem

Comment: do you know how to get the response in JSON format for send sms response

Comment: @fedrick No, I didn't work with twilio API. But I suggest you to set `Accept` request header to appropriate value. Somehow like this: `curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept:application/json'));`

Comment: It didn't worked <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>20003</Code><Message>Authenticate</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003</MoreInfo><Status>401</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>

Answer (score 5):

Here is a PHP - Curl implementation in a callable function

```
function send_sms($number,$body)
{
    $ID = '1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef12';
    $token = '1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef';
    $service = 'AB1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef';
    $url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' . $ID . '/Messages.json';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,$ID . ':' . $token);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        'To=' . rawurlencode('+' . $number) .
        '&MessagingServiceSid=' . $service .
        //'&From=' . rawurlencode('+18885550000') .
        '&Body=' . rawurlencode($body));

    $resp = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return json_decode($resp,true);
}
```

$ID and $token can be found under SMS / Dashboard / 'Show API Credentials'
https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/dashboard

(Optional) $service can be found under SMS / Messaging Services / 'SID' https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/services

Comment out 'MessagingServiceSid=' and uncomment 'From=' to use direct sending from a single phone number

Finally, key information can be found buried in the kb here https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#send-a-message-with-an-image-url

Comment: It's giving me error {"code":20003,"message":"Authenticate","more_info":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003","status":401}cc

Answer (score 2):

Curl Twilio PHP7+

```
$account_sid = 'account_sid';
$auth_token = 'auth_token';

$url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$account_sid/SMS/Messages";
$to = "+xxxxxx";
$from = "+xxxxxx"; // twilio trial verified number
$body = "using twilio rest api from Fedrick";
$data = array (
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Body' => $body,
);
$post = http_build_query($data);
$x = curl_init($url );
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$account_sid:$auth_token");
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$y = curl_exec($x);
curl_close($x);

//var_dump($post);
//var_dump($y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json
```

for json response

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.xml
```

for xml response